# Are there any tool to preview colors across devices?

Tags: color-spaces

Just wondering if anyone knows of an app or website that will approximate how images commonly appear on mac, pc, android or iPhone. Kind of like a proof setup view in Photoshop but for more color spaces and all at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

No app can even predict how an image will look on your own computer.

You could adjust the brightness and contrast, have an old monitor, have the curtains open on the window.

Remember that a screen is an output device, it is the last step and the result is "out" of the computer itself.

What you need to do is calibrate your own monitor. But you can not expect everyone does that or even try.

There is a joke I use in this cases.

There is a drunk man driving on the highway and he listens on the radio:
"There is a madman driving in the wrong direction on the highway" and he says: "One? There are a lot of them!.

You do not want to be the drunk man.

Comment: For a website like that to be possible every device would have to know exactly how wrongly it displays colors. If every device knew that, they would be able to compensate and show the correct colors instead which would make such a site obsolete.

Comment: That's why they invented sRGB... unfortunately, they then invented laptops & mobile phones... which all pretty much ignore it in favour of 'punch'. CRT monitors tended not to be able to do 'punch' after 10 years of being left switched on - they do 'pastel' instead  ;)